# Git Flow with branch unmerging

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-flow, methodology, git-revert

Here a long explanation with a simple problem at the end.

I'm working with a team on a pretty big project and we use a [git-flow](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/)-like methodology for our versioning / deployment.

So we have 3 major branch, `master`, `staging` and `dev` and we were developing feature from `master`. Recently, we choose to work around some issues and develop feature directly from `dev` (this way, we share feature and merge, without having to handle each other's conflicts.)

So, actually, we have something looking like that :

```
dev -F1---F2----F3---F4---o---o-
          \     /
feature    A---B
```

That mean, at the release date, we just have to merge `dev` with `master`, having all the features well tested on the `staging` environment.

The main problem is that a functionality can became unwanted at the end. We will then have to 'unmerge' the related branch.

It's pretty easy to unmerge an unwanted feature with this command :

```
$ git revert -m 1 F3
```

But other feature may contain the unwanted feature from `dev`.

**At this point, I'm wondering if making a checkout from `dev` is the best option and how correctly `unmerge` a feature...**

Comment: From a very pedantic point of view you have to release a new version if you plan to remove functionality. Or do you mean functionality that has been developed while a new release cycle and you don't want to add them into the release but rather then just remove them from the `dev` branch?

Comment: That's exactly it, we have a functionality developed inside our sprint, but at the end, it is not needed anymore (or is reported for the next sprint). So we have to remove it from the dev branch.

Comment: At this point, I don't see any other option then reverting the merges like you already mentioned.

Comment: Okay, I will try it on the current and next sprint, see how to deal with it in real time, and eventually I will find a better way or some solution if there's something wrong with this revert merge thing. 

(Actually, everything could go well, I don't know yet ...)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [git-flow](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/#hotfixes) you should use `revert` as [Hotfix](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/#hotfixes). Create a new hotfix branch, run `revert`, and then merge this branch to `dev` and `master`